# How to move a portlet into content's #content area?

Tags: plone, diazo

I would like to modify the content on the fly so I can later feed the modified version into my theme's content slot. The usecase is positioning the calendar portlet inside a collective.cover row/column/cell.

Here's what I tried:

```
<replace css:content="#content .row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(2) .tile.tile-edge">

  <!-- These work (meaning levels above current selection CAN be copied) -->
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  <xsl:copy-of select="../.." />
  <xsl:copy-of select="/" />

  <!-- However, neither of these do -->
  <xsl:copy-of css:select=".portletCalendar:first-child" />
  <xsl:copy-of select="//div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' portletCalendar ')]" />
  <xsl:copy-of select="//div[@id='portal-personaltools']" />

</replace>
```

Comment: why don't you add a calendar tile on collective.cover instead? :-)

Comment: Can you tell us more about what you're trying to do? It might be possible to do this without the XSL. (By the way, I don't think those mode="raw" attributes mean anything. "mode" is not an attribute of the copy-of tag. It only works on apply-template and template.)

Comment: @SteveM, as hvelarde pointed out, what I'm trying to achieve is emulating the existence of a calendar tile since I wouldn't like to create one by adopting a 3rd-party widget and I think it'd be difficult to reuse Plone's native because it's so portlet bound. Would you like me to explain better any specific aspect? BTW mode="raw" refs removed, thanks :-)

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the problem, but I'll take a shot at an answer anyway. Let me know if I'm on the wrong track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that the only problem you were having was relying on Diazo's facility for translating css selectors in XSL commands. It only works if the target is the currently selected node or a child of it. So, replace it with an XPath selector:

```
<!-- replace one part of content with another -->
<replace css:content="#content .row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(2) .tile.tile-edge">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//dl[@class='portlet portletCalendar']" />
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="raw" />
</replace>

<!-- make sure it doesn't show up in two places -->
<drop content="//dl[@class='portlet portletCalendar']" />
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks! Btw mode="raw" wasn't necessary.

Comment: The mode="raw" is only really needed if you need to do the drop.

Comment: Strangely enough, even though drops should be executed before replaces, mode="raw" wasn't needed.

Comment: Order of execution in XSL is going to have more to do with specificity of the selectors than order in the code. A bit of a puzzle!

Comment: Are you referring to <xsl:* /> tags only or are you also including the drop tag (because it's using a xpath selector)? For clarification in my case mode="raw" wasn't necessary even with identical (xpath) selectors on both xsl:copy-of and drop tags.